# Insert image into TCPDF multicell

Tags: php, tcpdf

Using `MultiCell()` method to achieve desired structure. Before I printed text in a cell and it was ok. Now i need to put an image instead. I tried to use inside `MultiCell()` the TCPDF's `Image()` method but it breaks the structure of my table. What is a workaround for this ? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a piece of code to test it?

Comment: No, currently I do not, the question is too old.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Image()` is used like a cell, this is probably why it break what is following in `MultiCell()`.

If you want to insert image into your text, it's better to use [`writeHTMLCell()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a8458280d15b73d3baffb28eebe2d9246) and use `<img />` tag.

```
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(100, 50, 10, 10, 'Lorem ipsum... <img src="..." /> Curabitur at porta dui...');
```

Comment: Yeah!, I found this project, and my solution was the same!

Comment: This doesn't support transparencies though